# Recovering encryption keys from previous Windows 10 installation

Tags: windows-10, security, encryption

I have installed a new version of Windows 10 on a new pc, and I've got some encrypted files from another windows PC which I haven't exported any keystores or anything from.

I have the Windows/User files from that build on an SSD which I am able to plug into the new PC. how can extract my previous keystores so that I am able to decrypt some of these encrypted files which I have?

Thanks very much!